# Automatic caret parameter tuning fails in glmnet

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

### Context and error message

I try to fit a two-class prediction model using glmnet within caret. I incur an error when using the caret default tune grids. I don't think it is due to wrongly formatted data because, when specifying my own tuning grid, there is no problem. 
The error message is:

```
Error in loop$lambda[loop$alpha == alph[i]] <- np[which.max(np)] : 
replacement has length zero
```

When checking the line at which the error occurs, one sees that R tries to find a maximum `which.na()` over a vector `np` of NA (the lambda values chosen by caret/glmnet?). I failed to debug this properly because I cannot find a way to step through each line of code after calling `train()`. I hope somebody with more experience can help me out.

### Minimal working example

I created a minimal working example by making my dataset as small as possible (it started with ~200 rows and ~40 columns) while preserving the error. Note that `manualModelFit` works fine but `modelFit` cannot be computed:

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
# create data frame of features
var1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
var2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1)
trainData <- data.frame(v1 = var1, v2 = var2)
# create fature vector of outcomes
trainClass <- as.factor(c('event','event','event','event','event','event','event','event','event','event','nonEvent','event','event','event','event','event','nonEvent'))
# set k for k-fold CV
kInner = 5
# set randomization seed
mySeed = 1622017
# set options for caret in fitControl
fitControl <- trainControl( method = 'cv', number = kInner, classProbs = TRUE, allowParallel = FALSE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, verboseIter = FALSE)
# run parameter tuning with a user-specified tuning grid
set.seed(mySeed)
myTuneGrid <- expand.grid(alpha = c(0,0.5,1), lambda = c(0,0.5,1))
manualModelFit <- train(x = trainData, y = trainClass, method = 'glmnet' , trControl = fitControl, metric = 'ROC', tuneGrid = myTuneGrid)
# run default parameter tuning
set.seed(mySeed)
modelFit <- train(x = trainData, y = trainClass, method = 'glmnet' , trControl = fitControl, metric = 'ROC')
```

### The questions

What causes the failure? 
Is this a bug within caret/glmnet or is this due to a property of the dataset that I overlooked? This error occurs in multiple datasets that I analyze.

Comment: Hi, I got the same problem with glmnet. In my case I have 1079 x 180 dataset and three classes. If I reduce dimentionality from 180 to 16 variables that describe 90% variance using PCA, the problem vanishes. No idea what happens...

Comment: @R Kiselev The reason why this solved your problem is maybe because it removed the factor variables which usually cause this problem. Can you check that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, the problem is with `tuneGrid`. At line 225 of `train.default` there is the code

```
tuneGrid <- models$grid(x = x, y = y, len = tuneLength, 
            search = trControl$search)
```

which for your example gives me

```
  alpha lambda
1  0.10     NA
2  0.55     NA
3  1.00     NA
Warning messages:
1: In lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground
2: from glmnet Fortran code (error code -2); Convergence for 2th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned
```

Obviously the `NA`'s for lambda result in the loop later on. `models$grid` is the following function:

```
findGrid <- function (x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
    if (search == "grid") {
        numLev <- if (is.character(y) | is.factor(y)) 
            length(levels(y))
        else NA
        if (!is.na(numLev)) {
            fam <- ifelse(numLev > 2, "multinomial", "binomial")
        }
        else fam <- "gaussian"
        init <- glmnet(as.matrix(x), y, family = fam, nlambda = len + 
                        2, alpha = 0.5)
        lambda <- unique(init$lambda)
        lambda <- lambda[-c(1, length(lambda))]
        lambda <- lambda[1:min(length(lambda), len)]
        out <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0.1, 1, length = len), 
                           lambda = lambda)
    }
    else {
        out <- data.frame(alpha = runif(len, min = 0, 1), lambda = 2^runif(len, 
                                                                           min = -10, 3))
    }
    out
}
```

which I renamed to `findGrid`. If you run it with `findGrid(trainData, trainClass, 3)` you should get the same warning and faulty grid back. In this binary scenario, all it does is:

```
init <- glmnet(as.matrix(x), y, family = "binomial", nlambda = len + 2, alpha = 0.5)
lambda <- unique(init$lambda) # contains one value, 
lambda <- lambda[-c(1, length(lambda))]
lambda <- lambda[1:min(length(lambda), len)]
out <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0.1, 1, length = len), 
                   lambda = lambda)
```

Now, after `lambda <- unique(init$lambda)`, `lambda` contains only one value which is `9.9e+35`. So whatever was intended afterwards with the indices isn't working anymore and will create `NA`'s instead. Increasing the number of iterations in `glmnet` did not avoid the error. So let's just skip those lines and use the grid obtained, to see if that fixes the problems.

```
init <- glmnet(as.matrix(x), y, family = "binomial", nlambda = len + 2, alpha = 0.5)
lambda <- unique(init$lambda) # contains one value, 
out <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0.1, 1, length = len), lambda = lambda)
modelFit <- train(x = trainData, y = trainClass, method = 'glmnet' , trControl = fitControl, metric = 'ROC', 
                  tuneGrid = out) # <-- use the tuneGrid we made
```

Which runs but also gives me 17 warnings, all of the form:

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Fold1: alpha=0.10, lambda=9.9e+35 Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed
```

So you're going to have to find a way to make a proper grid. This can be done by somehow fixing `glmnet` or by making some guesses / trial and error. However, I'm hesitant in looking into a method for a tune grid in this answer because it could very well be a data specific issue. A starting point would be to see if your complete dataset also has few observations in some categories.

Also, to debug this yourself, it is easiest to call `View(caret:::train.default)` to see the function. `:::` imports it from the hidden namespace. Next, you can copy all code into a `train2` function and use browser statements to debug the code line by line (at least, that's what I did). Any other functions that R cannot find also have to be prefixed with `caret:::`.

Comment: Great answer and explanation, thank you very much!
I will proceed by investigating whether the small number of observations in one class is a recurring theme in the other datasets.

Comment: @Vandenman this was an elaborate answer, thank you. can you think of any generic solution that presents a best guess which you could pass into the caret::train function? the reason is that i'm using caret for benchmarking algorithms, so I'm trying to find a first estimation with default parameters.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue, I thought I'd share my solution. As @Vandenman mentioned, you need a way of making a proper grid. This worked for me. Basically if you increase the number of lambdas you try in the `init <- glmnet(...)` step, you will get at least some that do not fail. I just picked 52 (I bet this number will work for you, but you could always change it, and computation time was negligible for my case). Then you choose `len` of them evenly spaced over those that did not fail.

```
my_glmnet <- getModelInfo("glmnet") %>% magrittr::extract2("glmnet")
my_glmnet$grid <- function (x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
  if (search == "grid") {
    numLev <- if (is.character(y) | is.factor(y)) 
      length(levels(y))
    else NA
    if (!is.na(numLev)) {
      fam <- ifelse(numLev > 2, "multinomial", "binomial")
    }
    else fam <- "gaussian"
    init <- glmnet(as.matrix(x), y, family = fam, nlambda = 52, alpha = 0.5)
    lambda <- unique(init$lambda)
    lambda <- lambda[-c(1, length(lambda))]
    l_seq <- seq(1, length(lambda), length = len) %>% round %>% unique
    lambda <- lambda[l_seq]
    out <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0.1, 1, length = len), 
                       lambda = lambda)
  }
  else {
    out <- data.frame(alpha = runif(len, min = 0, 1), lambda = 2^runif(len, 
                                                                       min = -10, 3))
  }
  out
}
```

Then you can run `train` with `method = my_glmnet`.

Comment: interesting that this solution worked for you specifying `nlambda = 52` as the default value in glmnet::glmnet is much higher: `glmnet(x, y, family=c("gaussian","binomial","poisson","multinomial","cox","mgaussian"),
    weights, offset=NULL, alpha = 1, nlambda = 100, ...`